# alpine Linuxへのawscliインストール

Tags: aws-cli

alpine Linuxにawscli v2をインストールしたところ下記のようになりました。

alpineを起動します。

```
$ docker run -it --rm alpine sh
/ # apk --update add curl
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r1)
(2/4) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.40.0-r0)
(3/4) Installing libcurl (7.67.0-r0)
(4/4) Installing curl (7.67.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r9.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r1.trigger
OK: 7 MiB in 18 packages
/ #
```

[Linux での AWS CLI バージョン 2 のインストール](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html)の手順でインストールすると、`./aws/install: line 78: /aws/dist/aws: not found`というエラーが出ます。

```
/ # curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
/ # curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 31.3M  100 31.3M    0     0  2047k      0  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:-- 2555k
/ # unzip -q awscliv2.zip
/ # ./aws/install
./aws/install: line 78: /aws/dist/aws: not found
You can now run: /usr/local/bin/aws --version
/ #
```

同じことをUbuntuで行ってもエラーにはなりませんでした。

Answer (score 3):

alpineは動作対象外である、というのが差し当たっての回答で、glibcを追加で入れると動作するようです。

- [前提条件](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-prereq)

  > CentOS、Fedora、Ubuntu、Amazon Linux 1、および Amazon Linux 2 の最近のディストリビューションで AWS CLI バージョン 2 がサポートされます。
- [[v2] installing on docker image fails · Issue #4685 · aws/aws-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4685#issuecomment-556436861)

  > The binaries we publish won't work on docker images based on alpine because we're compiling them against glibc.

  - `Dockerfile`サンプル: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4685#issuecomment-615872019

Answer (score 0):

awsコマンドは、下記のようにインストールされましたが、たどっていくと相対パスのシンボリックリンクが作られていることが原因のようでした。

```
/ # type aws
aws is /usr/local/bin/aws
/ # ls -l /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            37 May 20 09:12 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
/ # ls -l /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 20 09:12 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws -> ../dist/aws
/ #
```